# Lore before Metal Gear Solid 5: Phantom Pain

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid-series

I bought MGS5 yesterday and I'm really enjoing it. I've played MGS3 on the PS2 before and therefore "know" Ozelot. He seems completly different, but I know the name.

Now I wanted to ask if someone may know a good Video or source to get up to the MGS Lore until Phantom Pain, so I can get most of the references to the characters and the story.

Comment: The article that LoboDemon provided should get you up to speed, but if you have some time, you could watch [Portable Ops - "The Movie"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ljUp_4Crf0) and [Peace Walker - "The Movie"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Cy7E76mBL0) - Which are basically all cutscenes from those games cut together (with a little gameplay).

Comment: 'Ozelot' We must know imagine all of Ocelot's dialogue in an Aussie accent

Comment: I should say that Peace Walker is one of the best entries in the series, and that you should definitely play it if you get the opportunity. The gameplay is somewhat similar to The Phantom Pain and covers Big Boss's initial Mother Base, before it was raided by Skull Face. Portable Ops is "unrefined," for lack of a better term, but by the time PW came out, Kojima made the mechanics he used in Portable Ops much more refined.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Kojima didn't have anything to do with the mechanics in Portable Ops - he didn't direct the game or do game design for it. He has a producer credit, but that's just because it's a Metal Gear game developed in-house at Konami - he had the same credit on Acid and Ghost Babel, which were also directed and game designed by other people.

Comment: @recognizer Ah. Well, I suppose he built off of the unpolished but interesting operational mechanics in POps.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc I haven't played Portable Ops, so I always assumed Kojima wasn't too fond of it: http://i.imgur.com/NfhLjfP.gif

Comment: @recognizer I have not played it yet either, but I've heard that the controls aren't that great.  It's quite obviously the progenitor of the PW and TPP "Operations" mechanics -- the Mother Base management, etc, even if it was not made by Kojima. For example, the Fulton recovery system developed in Peace Walker and also used in TPP isn't present; instead, you have to extract the soldiers manually via a truck, sort of like how you have to take equipment with you in Operation Flashpoint. The only game in the franchise that I know Kojima actually hates is the NES version of Metal Gear 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here's a pretty good article from Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/what-you-need-to-know-about-metal-gear-solid-before-playing-mgs5-ground-zeroes/1100-6418103/)**

It's a story breakdown leading up to the event's of Ground Zeroes, the prolouge to Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain.